Implementing Waypoint Navigation for Bike Movement in Unity using NavMesh: Suggestions Needed
I'm currently working on a project where I need to implement waypoint navigation for a bike movement system in Unity. The goal is to accelerate the bike upon button press and have it smoothly follow a predefined waypoint path.
Here's a summary of what I've done so far:

Implemented basic bike movement controls, including acceleration upon
button press.
Created a series of waypoints that I want the bike to    follow.

However, I'm uncertain about the best approach for implementing the waypoint navigation. I've heard about NavMesh being useful for pathfinding in Unity, but I'm not sure if it's the right choice for a bike movement system.
Here's a snippet of the code I've written for reference:
Follow.AI
public class FollowAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    MotoController motoController;
    NavMeshAgent agent;
    Transform tr;
    public Transform target;
    Transform targetPrev;
    [SerializeField] Vector3 targetPoint;

    bool targetVisible;
    bool targetIsWaypoint;

    VehicleWaypoint targetWaypoint;
    public float followDistance;

    bool close;

    [Tooltip("Percentage of maximum speed to drive at")]
    [Range(0, 1)]
    public float speed = 1;
    float initialSpeed;
    float prevSpeed;
    public float targetVelocity = -1;

    [Tooltip("Mask for which objects can block the view of the target")]
    public LayerMask viewBlockMask;
    Vector3 dirToTarget; // Normalized direction to target
    float lookDot; // Dot product of forward direction and dirToTarget
    float steerDot; // Dot product of right direction and dirToTarget
    public int MaxSteeringAngle = 45;

    private void Start()
    {
        tr = transform;
        motoController =GetComponent<MotoController>();
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        initialSpeed = speed;

        InitializeTarget();
    }
    
    public void Follow()
    {
        if (target)
        {
            if (target != targetPrev)
            {
                InitializeTarget();
            }
            targetPrev = target;
            // Is the target a waypoint?
            targetIsWaypoint = target.GetComponent<VehicleWaypoint>();
            // Can I see the target?
            targetVisible = !Physics.Linecast(tr.position, target.position, viewBlockMask);
            if (targetVisible || targetIsWaypoint)
            {
                targetPoint = target.position;
            }
            if (targetIsWaypoint)
            {
                // if vehicle is close enough to target waypoint, switch to the next one
                if ((tr.position - target.position).sqrMagnitude <= targetWaypoint.radius * targetWaypoint.radius)
                {
                    target = targetWaypoint.nextPoint.transform;
                    agent.SetDestination(target.position);
                    targetWaypoint = targetWaypoint.nextPoint;
                }
            }

            close = (tr.position - target.position).sqrMagnitude <= Mathf.Pow(followDistance, 2) && !targetIsWaypoint;
            dirToTarget = (targetPoint - tr.position).normalized;

            Vector3 relativeVector = transform.InverseTransformPoint(targetPoint);
            float SteeringAngle = (relativeVector.x / relativeVector.magnitude) * MaxSteeringAngle;

            float angleToWaypoint = Vector3.Angle(tr.forward, dirToTarget);

            float deadzoneAngle = 15f; // Adjust as needed
            float leanInput = 0f;

            if (angleToWaypoint > deadzoneAngle)
            {
                steerDot = -Mathf.Sign(steerDot) * (close ? 0 : 1);
                motoController.turnLeanAmount = SteeringAngle;
            }
            else
            {
                steerDot = 0f; // No steering needed if within deadzone
            }

            // Set accel input
            if ((tr.position - target.position).sqrMagnitude > Mathf.Pow(followDistance, 2))
            {
                motoController.customAccelerationAxis = 1f; // Start acceleration on touch down
                motoController.rawCustomAccelerationAxis = 1f;
            }
            else
            {
                motoController.customAccelerationAxis = 0f; // Start acceleration on touch down
                motoController.rawCustomAccelerationAxis = 0f;
            }

            motoController.customSteerAxis = steerDot;
            motoController.customLeanAxis = leanInput;

        }
    }

    public void InitializeTarget()
    {
        if(target)
        {
            targetWaypoint = target.GetComponent<VehicleWaypoint>();
            if (targetWaypoint)
            {
                prevSpeed = targetWaypoint.speed;
            }
        }
    }


}

Mobile Input Controller
public class MobileController : MonoBehaviour
{
    MotoController motoController;
    public MobileButtonHandler forward, backward, left, right, wheelie;
    private bool isTouched;
    private float touchStartTime;
    private FollowAI followAI;
    void Start()
    {
        motoController = GetComponent<MotoController>();
        followAI = GetComponent<FollowAI>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(followAI != null)
        {
            if (forward.buttonPressed + backward.buttonPressed > 0)
            {
                followAI.Follow();
            }
        }
        MobileInput(left.buttonPressed+right.buttonPressed, ref motoController.customSteerAxis, motoController.steerControls.x, motoController.steerControls.y, false);
        MobileInput(forward.buttonPressed + backward.buttonPressed, ref motoController.customAccelerationAxis, 1, 1, false);
        MobileInput(left.buttonPressed+right.buttonPressed, ref motoController.customLeanAxis, motoController.steerControls.x, motoController.steerControls.y, false);
        MobileInput(forward.buttonPressed + backward.buttonPressed, ref motoController.rawCustomAccelerationAxis, 1, 1, true);
        motoController.wheelieInput = System.Convert.ToBoolean(wheelie.buttonPressed);
        
    }
    
    private void SetBreaks()
    {
        MobileInput(-1, ref motoController.rawCustomAccelerationAxis, 1f, 0.1f, false);
        MobileInput(-1, ref motoController.rawCustomAccelerationAxis, 1f, 0.1f, false);
    }
    float MobileInput(int instruction, ref float axis, float sensitivity, float gravity, bool isRaw)
    {
        var r = instruction*2;
        var s = sensitivity;
        var g = gravity;
        var t = Time.unscaledDeltaTime;

        if (isRaw)
            axis = r;
        else
        {
            if (r != 0)
                axis = Mathf.Clamp(axis + r * s * t, -1f, 1f);
            else
                axis = Mathf.Clamp01(Mathf.Abs(axis) - g * t) * Mathf.Sign(axis);
        }

        return axis;
    }

}

I'd appreciate any suggestions or insights on the following points:

Is NavMesh a suitable choice for implementing waypoint navigation
with turning for a bike movement system?
If so, how can I integrate NavMesh into my existing code to achieve
smooth waypoint navigation with turning?
Are there any alternative approaches or Unity packages that might be better suited for this task?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

its not wrong, it is nothing more or less than a system that provides a path to get from a->b


Are there any alternative approaches or Unity packages that might be better suited for this task?

From your requirements it sounds like a better alternative to NavMesh is Splines (available from Unity 2022)
This video is a great intro for setting splines up: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-o2e4KxbW4
Here is a link to a post that includes some code to have custom movement of an object along a spline: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78316304/4640357
It would look something like this and might simplify the waypoint code a lot
public SplineContainer spline;
public float speed = 1;
private float splineDistance = 0;
private float distanceCovered = 0;
private void Start()
{
    splineDistance = spline.CalculateLength();
}
public void Follow()
{
    distanceCovered += speed * Time.deltaTime;
    float distancePercentage = distanceCovered / splineDistance;
    Vector3 currentSplinePosition = spline.EvaluatePosition(distancePercentage);
}

